vscode with Microsoft C++ Extension does not find /usr/local/include
I installed Visual Studio Code on Linux Mint with the C++ Extension from Microsoft. Since I want to write a program that connects to PostgreSQL, I downloaded the required sources and compiled and installed as described. To be able to compile the Quick Example the includes from PSQL client library should be found by the compiler. I can find the includes in folder "/usr/local/include". So I want to add this folder in the c_cpp_properties.json. Unfortunately, vscode does not find this folder and tells me:
.

This folder definitely exists.

Yes, I switched vscode on and off again


Since I installed vscode as "Flatpak" application, it has restricted access to the file system. I uninstalled and installed the .deb package from https://code.visualstudio.com. This installation has access to the /usr/local folder.
